# When Communicate with?

Tags: sentence-structure

Why was not it used "with" in the following sentence?

> Because architecture grows out of human needs and aspirations, it
>   clearly communicates cultural values.

Shouldn't it was this?:

> Because architecture grows out of human needs and aspirations, it
>   clearly communicates **with** cultural values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

> Architecture communicates cultural values

This the correct version.

**Long answer:**

It's the difference between a direct object and indirect object.

For 'communicate', what you're communicating about is the direct object, so you should not use a preposition such as 'with'. Who you give that information to is the indirect object, so you should use a preposition such as 'with'. In your example, the cultural values are the subject of that communication, and those values are given to anyone who looks at that architecture. So it would look like this:

> The architecture communicates cultural values **with** its viewers.

Either can stand on its own, for example:

> The architecture communicates cultural values
>
> The architecture communicates **with** its viewers

But which object is direct or indirect remains the same.